# Why it is not possible to place type parameters after method name?

Tags: java, generics

If fact, the question is:

***What problems may occure if it would be possible to place type parameters after method name?***

---

E.g.:

```
import com.google.common.base.Predicate;
static import com.google.common.base.Predicates.alwaysTrue;

Predicate<SomeType> p = alwaysTrue<SomeType>();
```

---

**Update:**

I know that you could pass type parameter this way:

```
Predicate<SomeType> p = Predicates.<SomeType>alwaysTrue();
```

Comment: What's your problem with the current way to parametrize methods?

Comment: @Ordous It is impossible to parametrize staticaly imported methods…

Comment: It's just the way the language was built, more or less.

Comment: @Errandir `Predicate.<SomeType>alwaysTrue()` will work however. As to *why* this is acceptable, while the syntax you proposed is not - you may want to edit your question, as it seems answerers are assuming you don't know how to type your method and are asking how to do it.

Comment: The question implicitly asks: Is it possible that in some version of Java there would be alternative way to pass type parameters to methods, or it is totally impossible?

Comment: I suppose you could design a language like this.

Comment: I still don't understand the purpose of putting the generic there? What would that syntax indicate on a call that the diamond operator doesn't already do better?

Comment: Note that this doesn't have to be a static import - all the same things happen with private static methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 distinct questions here:

Why is a class or object needed to parametrize a method?

```
public class Test {
    private static <T> void staticMethod() {}
    private <T> void method() {}
    public Test() {
        method();                // Works!
        <Integer>method();       // Doesn't work!
        this.<Integer>method();  // Works again!
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        staticMethod();                // Works!
        <Integer>staticMethod();      // Doesn't work
        Test.<Integer>staticMethod(); // Works again!
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I cannot give an answer to that...

Second question: Why are method type parameters put before the method (As opposed to class parameters, which are *after* the class)?

Here I do have a hunch - one of the problems is generic constructors. Generic constructors can have type parameters just as any other method, and those can be independent of the class type parameters:

```
public class Class<T> {
    public <V>Class(V arg) {

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new <Number>Class<Object>(0);
    }
}
```

This is valid syntax, and the first type parameter is the method parameter, while the second one is the class type parameter.

There needs to be a mechanism to distinguish between those, and remember - either can be omitted on the developers whim, because of backwards compatibility!

I cannot think of any other way to do it, rather than putting them on different sides of the constructor call.

I *imagine* there is a similar fringe case of ambiguity with a parametrized method being called without an object or class, but I can't think of any right now.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is why did the Java designers design the syntax that way: My best guess is that it's because method names have their own namespace separate from variable/field names, which means it's legal for a method name to have the same name as a variable or field, and the context determines which one is being used.  Thus:

```
x = myName;
```

looks for a variable or field named `myName`, while

```
x = myName(arg);
```

looks for a method named `myName`.  The left `(` is what tells the compiler to look for a method instead of a variable.  This way, both statements can be accepted by the compiler even when `myName` has legal meanings both as a variable and as a method.

If the syntax were that type parameters went after the method name:

```
x = myName<T>(arg);
```

the compiler would be very confused.  Is this expression the variable `myName`, followed by the `<` (less-than) operator, followed by a variable named `T`, followed by a `>` operator, followed by an expression in parentheses?  Or is it a method call with a type parameter?  It may be that there is no case where there are two possible interpretations (since `<` and `>` are not legal on `boolean` arguments in Java), but it seems reasonable that the designers thought it would be too much of a burden on the compiler, or too much of a burden to devise the language rules correctly to work in all cases.

**P.S.** Just to give you an idea of what kind of headaches could be caused:  The first assignment is legal in Java:

```
// instance members
int name1, name2, name3;
public <T> boolean name2(int argument) { ... }

// some statement later on in some method
boolean x = name1<name2>>(name3);        // legal
boolean x = name1<name2<name4>>(name3);  // would be legal syntax if type parameters appeared
                                         // after method names
```

Keeping in mind that the rules for interpreting `>>` are special--it's treated as two seperate `>` characters in a type context (so that you can have `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`), but as a shift operator otherwise.  I wouldn't want to be the one writing either the compiler code or the language rules to make sure both are handled correctly.

Comment: For now it is the best answer, but I wait for the problem example with mathematically strict explaination of it's essentiality.

Comment: You may be waiting a very long time.  Language designers don't need to "prove" that something could possibly be ambiguous.  If something could make the language rules very difficult to understand, put too big a burden on compiler writers, or lead to code that may be confusing to readers, those are good enough reasons not to allow something.